# How to represent data in one byte array using Byte Buffer?

Tags: java, arrays, bytebuffer, endianness

I have my below layout in which I need to represent my data and then finally I need to make one byte array out of that.

```
// below is my data layout -
// data key type which is 1 byte
// data key len which is 1 byte
// data key (variable size which is a key_len)
// timestamp (sizeof uint64_t)
// data size (sizeof uint16_t)
// data (variable size = data size)
```

So I started like this but I am having some confusion so got stuck -

```
// data layout
byte dataKeyType = 101;
byte dataKeyLength = 3;

// not sure how to represent key here

long timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis(); // which is 64 bit
short dataSize = 320; // what does this mean? it means size of data is 320 bytes?

// and now confuse as well how to represent data here, we can have any string data which can be converted to bytes


// and then make final byte array out of that
```

How do I represent this in one byte array using Byte Buffer? Any simple example will help me to understand better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    byte keyType = 101;
    byte keyLength = 3;
    byte[] key = {27, // or whatever your key is
                  55, 
                  111};
    long timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();

    // If your data is just a string, then you could do the following.
    // However, you will likely want to provide the getBytes() method
    // with an argument that specifies which text encoding you are using.
    // The default is just the current platform's default charset.
    byte[] data = "your string data".getBytes();
    short dataSize = (short) data.length;

    int totalSize = (1 + 1 + keyLength + 8 + 2 + dataSize);
    ByteBuffer bytes = ByteBuffer.allocate(totalSize);

    bytes.put(keyType);
    bytes.put(keyLength);
    bytes.put(key);
    bytes.putLong(timestamp);
    bytes.putShort(dataSize);
    bytes.put(data);

    // If you want everthing as a single byte array:
    byte[] byteArray = bytes.array();
```

Comment: Thanks gharma for the help. Can you explain me how did you calculated `totalSize`? Just got confuse little bit.

Comment: totalSize should equal the total number of bytes in the final byteArray. So, 1 byte for the keyType, 1 byte for the keyLength, <keyLength> bytes for the key, 8 bytes for the timestamp, 2 bytes for the dataSize, and <dataSize> bytes for the data.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Java's DataOutputStream class to dynamically generate the byte array. For example:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(baos);

dos.writeByte(keyType);
dos.writeByte(keyLength);
dos.write(new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, ..., key_len-1 }, 0, key_len);
dos.writeLong(System.currentTimeMillis());
dos.writeShort(320);
dos.write(new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, ..., 319 }, 0, 320);
```

You should replace the two `new byte[] {}` parts by the array that contains the key bytes and the array that contains the data, respectively.